# How to split JSON values if it contains "Most_Likely"?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse through JSON values and parse what I need.

Basically, I only want to capture values that are denoted as "Most_Likely".

In addition, if there is an OR statement, I need to separate out those values.

Here is my attempt at doing this, but I'm getting a JS error :

```
for (i = 0; i < obj1.Summary.length; i++) {


for (j in obj1.Summary[i]) {
    
    if (j.indexOf('Most_Likely') && obj1.Summary[i][j].indexOf('|OR|') >= 0){
        var tempvalue = obj1.Summary[i][j].indexOf('Most_Likely').split(" |OR| ");
        attributesvalues.push(tempvalue);
        alert(attributesvalues);
    }
    else{
    //do nothing
    }
    
    
   }

}
```

//sample JSON

```
var obj1 = {
 "Summary" : 
    [
        {
            "host:Most_Likely" : "www.google.com", 
            "host:Indicative" : "www.yahoo.com |OR| www.google.com", 
            "term:Most_Likely" : "cars" |OR| new cars |OR| SUVs, 
            "term:Indicative" : "automatic |OR| Lexus |OR| SUVs |OR| Civic" 
        }
    ]
 };
```

Comment: An [alternative implementation](http://jsbin.com/duwudogena/1/edit?js,console) in case you're curious about a more "functional programmy" way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in this line

```
var tempvalue = obj1.Summary[i][j].indexOf('Most_Likely').split(" |OR| ");
```

`indexOf` returns position (type number), split there is in String object that's why you get error.

```
var attributesvalues = [],
    tempvalue;

for (var i = 0; i < obj1.Summary.length; i++) {
  for (var j in obj1.Summary[i]) {
    if (j.indexOf('Most_Likely') >= 0 && obj1.Summary[i][j].indexOf('|OR|') >= 0) {
      tempvalue = obj1.Summary[i][j].split(" |OR| ");
      attributesvalues.push(tempvalue);
    } else { 
    }
  }
}

console.log(attributesvalues);
```

Answer (score 1):

As written I see a few potential issues here.

1. You have `j.indexOf('Most_Likely')` as part of a boolean condition. `indexOf` returns -1 if the element is not found, which is considered [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). You probably want this to read `j.indexOf('Most_Likely') !== -1`.
2. In your example `obj1` the value you have for `term:Most_Likely` is `"chars" |OR| new cars |OR| SUVs`. It looks to me like you terminated your string prematurely causing JS to wonder, "what's all this |OR| stuff?"
3. You attempt to call `split` on an integer in this line: `obj1.Summary[i][j].indexOf('Most_Likely').split(" |OR| ")`. As previously noted `indexOf` returns the index an item is found at. If you remove the `indexOf` bit from this line it might do what you want it to.

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't need the empty `else` clause after the if.